# Selection not visible

Tags: selection-tools

I'm working on a project in Blender 2.8. Somehow after importing a few OBJ into the scene (not sure if it's related), my selection outlines etc disappeared. On the attached picture I'm in edit mode and the 2 stretched polygons are selected. They should be orange, but they're not. Selection outline also doesn't work in other modes. In viewport shading outline is set on. Is there any other place where I could've turned it off by mistake?[image: Car without selection]

Comment: Visibility options are on the upper right corner, near the wireframe/solid/lookdev/render view icons. Look at them.

Answer (score 12):

You disabled Display overlays.

To enable [Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/overlays.html) you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> by default.

[image: overlay]